# Native C++ OpenGL to Managed C++ to Winform C# - Slow during Debug

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, opengl

I am working on a small engine which can be run as standalone or within a winform application.
So far I got both working, the only issue I have is that during debugging in visual studio, the winform application's gamescreen updates slowly, which results in the player lagging.

But if I open the created .exe without the debugger, it runs smoothly.

So that I can easily edit the winform, see my changes and play the game without lag I am asking you guys if you could help me.

You can see my code here:

https://github.com/insanepure/SweetEngine/

Sweet.Editor is the C# Winform, which depends on the Sweet.Wrapper, which is the managed C++ application. This depends on Sweet.Game (for game specific components, also that can be run as standalone) and Sweet.Engine (which depends on Sweet Core etc but I abstracted that so that you only need to include Sweet.Engine within Sweet.Game)

So the tool works is that it get's the HWND of a specific Panel and then creates the engine with that HWND, instead of creating a new one. That is the only difference between standalone and tool.

The problem may be because I am running my own loop within SweetEngine. I tried to change this so that the winform calls Update and Render, but this somehow was slower than doing it in a seperate loop.
Also I am not sure why this is faster than making the application call Update and Render.

Another problem I encountered is that I can't debug my native c++ code, so I can not step inside of it. Can this be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to WPF and using a class that inherits from usercontrol, that way I can draw when OnPaint() is called, also I am using a timer to call OnPaint 60 times a second. Now it's working better.